# Maven 3.2.3 archetype number

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-3, maven-archetype

When i go to cmd prompt and use cmd "**mvn archetype:generate**", I have a list of archetype number.
Does anyone know about the archetype number for **maven-archetype-webapp** in **Maven 3.2.3**?

Comment: What do you mean by `number for maven-archetype-webapp in Maven 3.2.3?`

Answer (score 0):

The number for maven-archetype-webapp is

> 494

Answer (score 0):

The number for maven-archetype-webapp is 557